# Sending email using ASP.NET I am getting this error

Tags: asp.net, smtp, gmail

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u6sm344516ibd.6

I have my code like this?

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Error Occred in the application:";
message.Body = ex.Message;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if setting the EnableSsl property for SmtpClient to true and specifying the credentials would help.

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

Comment: its still saying the same thing? sir

Comment: do I need to provide Credential must and should? thanks if i use port number 467 what will happen?

Comment: I receive the following error if EnableSsl is set to true and credentials are not provided "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required..."

Comment: Thanks Abatishchev.. but its giving this error when I am trying to send to hotmailDelivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    xxxxd@hotmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (state 14).

Comment: Please check Configuring mail clients at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287 and make sure that the destination address used is valid. Also keep in mind that there are domains that reject emails from smtp servers considered that are used for sending spam.

Answer (score 4):

the SMTP server required that you use a secure connection

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+mail+with+gmail+smtp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 found a lot of info here. have a look :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the appropriate properties of the SmtpClient instance to enable TSL/SSL, and set credentials. Check out this for more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL).

Comment: If i use port 25 do I need to use the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

For gmail Smtp server, use port 587. Port 465 has problems. Make sure you also pass in your correct gmail address and the password that you use with that address/account.  Finally, ensure you have set your gmail account to accept connections from other email apps.